# Backend for WoIP on WebRTC, asterisk?

Tags: webrtc, asterisk, sip, freeswitch

I want add feature on my site: receiving phone calls in browser. What is the best way to realize it (backend)? I was read asterisk is bad choise for WebRTC protocol. Do you get me advice, what me do? Or link to article about that.

Comment: The Phono javascript SDK from Tropo provides an easy way to do it, https://phono.com/. Ultimately if you want to make or receive calls from the PSTN you'll have to pay someone.

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to answer without more details about the constraints you have, and some answers already mention using hosted JS SDKs as a quick solution that doesn't require you to build and maintain your own infrastructure.

For what concerns your observation on Asterisk, it's not true that it can't support WebRTC. Take a look at [respoke](https://www.respoke.io/), which is Digium's "WebRTC extension" for Asterisk. The Asterisk module is free, but the service comes at a price.

Still in the area of building your own infrastructure, you should take a look at [FreeSWITCH and its 'verto' module](https://freeswitch.org/verto-not-just-for-call-signaling/). In this case you're not constrained to use a non-free service, but you need to build the signalling platform too.

A popular WebRTC/VoIP gateway is [Janus](https://janus.conf.meetecho.com/index.html), which you may also find interesting.

Answer (score 0):

If your primary goal is to have a button thats ends up calling your phone or another web browser, I shall recommend going with a Call API provider like Twilio or Plivo and many more.

Its easier to achieve the functionality without really having to understand and debug the entire system. And with large customer bases these are really reliable services and gives you a lot of flexibility w.r.t features and pricing.

There is a pricing involved per call but if the call is a ancillary part of the site and not the primary function, it preferable not to go the Asterik / FreeSwitch etc path at the moment.